# Pretty urls in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-routing

Im trying to make it work. THis is my rake routes right now:

```
groups GET    /groups(.:format)                           groups#index
                         POST   /groups(.:format)                           groups#create
               new_group GET    /groups/new(.:format)                       groups#new
              edit_group GET    /groups/:id/edit(.:format)                  groups#edit
                   group GET    /groups/:id(.:format)                       groups#show
                         PATCH  /groups/:id(.:format)                       groups#update
                         PUT    /groups/:id(.:format)                       groups#update
                         DELETE /groups/:id(.:format)                       groups#destroy
```

what i want to do is remove "groups" from the link and add slug instead of id.
This is my controller right now:

```
class GroupsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :find_group, only: [:show]
  after_action :assign_slug, only: [:create, :update]

  def index
    @groups = Group.all
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @group = Group.new
  end

  def create
    @group = Group.new(group_params)
    if @group.save
      flash.notice = "Group has been successfully created!"
      redirect_to @group
      binding.pry
    else
      flash.alert = "oops!"
      redirect_to action: :new
    end
  end

  private
    def group_params
      params.require(:group).permit(:title, :description, :country, :city, :category_id)
    end

    def find_group
      @group = Group.find_by_slug(params[:slug])
    end

    def assign_slug
      @group.update(slug: @group.title.parameterize)
    end

end
```

How do i make it work? Thanks.:)

Comment: Can you post some example routes? I understanded: www.domain.com/slug just as route?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is what you want:

```
routes.rb

get ':slug', to: 'pages#show', as: :groups_show
put ':slug', to: 'pages#update', as: :groups_update
delete ':slug', to: 'pages#destroy', as: :groups_delete
```

This way the slug will be catched as param and sended to the controller.

Comment: Added option without gems.